# TangowithDjango - makemigrations - App 'rango' could not be found. is it in INSTALLED_APPS?

Tags: django

I'm having the following Django apps structure:

```
sarpedon33
   rango
       migrations
   sarpedon33
   media
   static
   templates
```

I get this comment "App 'rango' could not be found. is it in INSTALLED_APPS?" when I try to makemigrations for rango app.

settings.py is like this :

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/' # You may find this is already defined as such.

STATICFILES_DIRS = (STATIC_PATH,)
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') # Absolute path to the media directory

SECRET_KEY = '****************************************************'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```

Comment: ...well, like the error says, is `'rango'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Answer (score 4):

Add the `rango` app to the `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rango', # <--- HERE ----
)
```

Comment: My very basic problem solved. Thanks a lot catavaran

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone got here because they are seeing this error even though they actually **have** the app listed in INSTALLED_APPS, like it was my case working with legacy code.

Do not use project_dir.app_name, or any similar structure. Write only the app name, e.g.:

This is **wrong**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'directory.my_app_name',
)
```

This is correct:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'my_app_name',
)
```